# How to save Face biometrics as a video Flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

I'm a flutter developer and I'm trying to build an ios/android app that records a selfie video, is it possible to track face movement and gives instructions while the selfie video is recording ? is there any package that I can work with or any helpful article?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `ML Kit's face detection API` which can detect faces in an image, identify key facial features, and get the contours of detected faces.

> Because ML Kit can perform face detection in real-time, you can use it
> in applications like video chat or games that respond to the player's
> expressions.
>
> [ML Kit's face detection API](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection)

Take a look at these resources:

- https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit
- https://medium.com/codechai/ml-kit-and-face-detection-in-flutter-c7bca082fdda
- https://github.com/muratcancicek/flutter_head_based_pointing